# `this` in callback points to wrong object

Tags: typescript

I have this viewModel:

```
import app = require("durandal/app");
import appViewModel = require("appViewModel");
import dataService = require("dataService");

class Home{
    section = ko.observable<string>();
    activeScreen = ko.observable<string>("nativeLanguage/selectNativeLanguage");

constructor() {
    app.on('home:activateView').then(this.activateView);
}

activateView(view) {
    this.activeScreen(view);
}

activate() {
    return this.getSection();
}

getSection() {
    return dataService.getSection('HOME_PAGE').then((data) => {
        this.section(data.results[0]);
    });
}
}
export = Home;
```

This compiles without error.

However, when it runs, and activateView is called as a callback, `this` is pointing to `app` not to `Home` so the activeScreen property is undefined.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing the function to someone else to call in `.then(this.activateView);` you need to preserve the context yourself, best if you do : `.then((view)=>this.activateView(view));`

More about `this` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Comment: Yes, this is called lexical scope and more info can be found here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-lambdas-and-using-39this39

Answer (score 2):

While you have your answer, the way I prefer is a bit different:

> convert *function/method* definition - into "*property* referencing function"

```
// instead of class method
// public activateView(view) {

// use the "property"
public activateView = (view) => {
    this.activeScreen(view);
}
```

That will reduce the need to pass explicit params like this

```
.then((view) => this.activateView(view))
```

because this will work again:

```
.then(this.activateView)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do then(this.activateView.bind(this))